# Странный редирект nginx

Tags: nginx, apache, phpmyadmin

Настраиваю связку nginx + apache + mysql(mariadb) + phpmyadmin.
При обращении на адрес, nginx должен передать запрос в apache.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name egas77.ru;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
}
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
    root /usr/share;
}}
```

При обращении на egas77.ru меня редиректит на http://egas77.ru:8080/phpmyadmin/.
И если в apache выставить прослушивание порта только с локального адреса, то сайт естественно не открывается. Вопрос такой - откуда берется redirect?

Comment: Из php. Допишите слеш в proxy_pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо. Решение в первом комментарии. Достаточно было добавить слэш в директиву proxy_pass

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119779/discussion-on-answer-by-starteg---nginx).